# consulta entre 5 tablas Sql Server (algunas sin relacion directa)

Tags: sql-server

Necesito completar esta consulta (sql server 2008):

```
select EstadoCotizacion.var_eco_descripcion, id_cot, 
       Usuario.var_usr_nombres, fec_cot_emision, fec_cot_aceptacion 
       from COTIZACION 
       inner join USUARIO 
          on COTIZACION.id_eje=usuario.id_USR 
       inner join estadocotizacion 
          on COTIZACION.id_eco=ESTADOCOTIZACION.id_eco
```

**para mostrar algo asi :**

```
var_eco_descripcion - id_cot - var_ser_descripcion - (var_usr_nombres & var_usr_appaterno & var_usr_apmaterno) - suma(valor_unitario_item) - fec_cot_emision - fec_cot_aceptacion
```

dispongo de las siguientes tablas

**dbo.cotizacion**

```
[id_cot]
[id_eje] -----> es igual al campo [id_usr] de dbo.usuario
[fec_cot_emision]
[fec_cot_aceptacion]
[var_cot_observacion]
[id_cli]
[id_eco]
```

**dbo.estadocotizacion**

```
[id_eco]
[var_eco_descripcion]
```

**dbo.usuario**

```
[id_usr]
[var_usr_login]
[var_usr_password]
[var_usr_nombres]
[var_usr_appaterno]
[var_usr_apmaterno]
```

**dbo.servicios**

```
[id_ser]
[id_ane]
[var_ser_descripcion]
```

**dbo.detallecotizacion**

```
[id_dco]
[id_cot]
[id_ser]
```

**dbo.ItemDetalleCotizacion**

```
[Id_Item]
[id_dco]
[Descripción_Item]
[Cantidad_Item]
[Valor_Unitario_Item]
```

Comment: En caso que realmente no tuvieran relación no es posible sacar información; pero si observas bien lo que pusiste de las tablas encontraras que sí; tu planteamiento **para mostrar algo asi** pienso debiste colocarlo **var_eco_descripcion, id_cot, var_ser_descripcion, (var_usr_nombres & var_usr_appaterno & var_usr_apmaterno), suma(valor_unitario_item), fec_cot_emision, fec_cot_aceptacion** los guiones quesean coma para identificar cada dato, de lo contrario se *"interpreta"* como una operación aritmética.

Comment: y qué has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Para vincular las demás tablas que están faltando solo debes especificar la relación el el ON del JOIN con el que relaciones las tablas. En este caso solo tú conoces los campos relacionados, ya sea por Clave foránea (FK) o no. En caso de no conocer cuales son, revisa los datos en las tablas que te faltan para luego vincularlos.

Debes tomar en cuenta también los diferentes JOIN que puedes usar, left, right, inner, full outer join. Dependiendo de los datos relacionados. En todo caso empieza con INNER JOIN, para solo obtener los datos que existen en todas las tablas relacionadas.

Algo más, en tu estructura noto algo en las tablas **dbo.cotizacion, dbo.detallecotizacion y dbo.itemDetalleCotizacion**:

- dbo.cotizacion: parece tener como PK, id_cot.
- dbo.detalleCotizacion: parece tener una PK compuesta con **id_cot** y **id_dco**.
- dbo.ItemDetalleCotizacion: parece tener una PK compuesta con **Id_Item** y **id_dco**, pero donde quedo **id_cot**??.

Te recomiendo que revises los datos y armes un diagrama de tus tablas para luego crear la sentencia que te ayudará. Saludos.